# Arquillian Maven configuration

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian for Ejb unit test. I am using jboss-eap-5.1. Can anyone please tell me what is the configuration in maven for Arquillian  which uses jboss-eap-5.1

Answer (score 1):

This blog from howtojboss.com explains how to setup EAP 5 with Arquillian:
http://howtojboss.com/2012/03/14/integration-testing-w-maven-arquillian-jboss-eap-5/

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/JBoss+AS+5.1+-+Remote